# I want to make a line in a listbox visible after it is it is added

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a line visible after it is entered in my system.

This is how i have done this in the past but i cant seem to get it to work on this problem. just not sure where to fit it on or what i need o change

```
ListView1.ListItems(itmx.Index).Selected = True
        ListView1.SetFocus
        ListView1.ListItems(itmx.Index).EnsureVisible

Private Sub CommandButtonUpdate_Click()

If myindex = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Must Search for Area before using UPDATE "
    Exit Sub
Else

    result = MsgBox("Do you want to replace " & itmx & " with " & TextBox_Area.Text, vbYesNo)
    If result = vbYes Then

        Sheets("Areas").Cells(myindex + 1, 1).Value = TextBox_Area

        PopulateList
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

I want the line that has "Populated the list" to be visible so the user knows there information has been processed.

Comment: *"so the user knows there information has been processed"* why not use a simple message box that says "Data has been processed"?

Comment: I already have many message boxes and the users will be entering in a lot of data. I just this it would be better if they can see it in the list rather then a message box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the list item you use `ListBox.ListIndex = Index`.  In your case probably `ListView1.ListIndex = itmx.Index`